# Mysql5 hash generator VBA

Tags: vba, excel, hash, sha, mysql5

Is mysql5 algoritm is SHA-1(SHA-1($pass)) ?

Then i trying this http://vb.wikia.com/wiki/SHA-1.bas script, with function `=SHA1HASH(SHA1HASH("test"))` i get `c4033bff94b567a190e33faa551f411caef444f2` but Mysql5 hash must be `94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29`

How to convert string to Mysql5 hash in VBA?

[image]

I have found why this hapens,

because Sha1 provided in Hex, but Mysql5 in binary

Comment: Are you sure $pass = "test"?

    SELECT SHA1(SHA1('test')) = c4033bff94b567a190e33faa551f411caef444f2

Comment: Yes i am sure http://i.stack.imgur.com/rnpfI.png

Comment: what did you use to calculate the following hash: 94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29

Comment: To generate the hash provided, try in mysql `SELECT PASSWORD("test")`, If you need to use the password hashing outside of mysql - I would recommend that you use sha1 - with salting.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password

Comment: I need Excel VBA. I use http://www.insidepro.com/hashes.php?lang=eng to calculate the following hash: 94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29

Comment: In that case you will need to locate the hashing algorithm use by MySQL in the PASSWORD function and reverse engineer a solution to use in VBA - as the PASSWORD function does not use a unsalted SHA1 or MD5 hashing method.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the string `94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29` was generated via the MySQL function `PASSWORD()`.

```
SELECT PASSWORD("test") /* *94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29 */
```

As recommended by the MySQL documentation if you need to maintain all you hash code in excel you need to change your original hashing process to use something like SHA1.

From the MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password
*The PASSWORD() function is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should not use it in your own applications. For that purpose, consider MD5() or SHA1() instead.*

Comment: I do not want change anything, i want get *94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29 from string test in EXCEL VBA

Comment: Why do you want to get that particular hash - it is a proprietary hashing method used by MySQL 5 to generate internal hashes for MySQL.

There own documentation recommends that you do not use it.

Unless you have already gone down a irreversible route I highly recommend you switch to a non-proprietary option.

If you NEED to use the MySQL PASSWORD() function, you will need to install connect to either a local or remote MySQL server from your VBA module, run the following SQL `SELECT PASSWORD("test")` and get the result.

Comment: i have already generated passwords in Mysql5 hashes from passwords, i just want to compare if password has been changed